# Why my Magento 1.9 admin panel is too slow, Take more than a min after click on any button

Tags: magento-1.9, slowbackend

I am facing the problem in my magento website, My magento admin panel is too slow. When I click on any menu tab like orders, add new product etc, it take more than a minute to open that page. And normally its shows these 2 error:

> Error 503 Service Unavailable Service Unavailable Guru Meditation XID: 1386574399 Varnish cache server

and:

> Error 504 timeout

I am not sure how these error are coming, I already uninstall extra extensions Note This is happening for last 5 or 6 days, Before that everything was fine. And my website frontend is also too slow Please advise Thank you

Comment: Enable Magento Profiler (just google how to do that). Post profiler output here if you want to be helped. Otherwise it all will be just general assumptions.

Comment: Have you recently made changes to your Varnish config? Uninstalled an extension that works with Varnish? https://www.section.io/blog/varnish-cache-503-error-guru-meditation/

Answer (score 0):

This kind of performance issue can have multiple causes, I would begin to look at these things first:

Are your sessions stored in files? If so, check the space left on the server, usually with this with Linux:

```
df -h
```

If the sessions are in a database, are you using Redis? If so, flush Redis, usually with the command **flushdb** or **flushall** using redis-cli.

More on Redis over here: https://redis.io/commands/flushall

If the sessions are in your main database server, then check the space left on the DB server.

Check also the number of connections to the DB server, you might want to restart your DB server to see if that is the cause and to start investigating why...

Good luck.